# Converting nested JSON streamind data to ndjson

Tags: python, json, ndjson

I am currently working with Twitter stream data and I want to convert the nested JSON response to ndjson using python. I saw a few examples using `json.normalize` but that just seperated it to one level and my output has much deeper levels. I am new to JSON and tried searching for any examples but did not find any.
Here's how my streaming output looks like:
[image: Streamed twitter response]

I want to flatten out the JSON to ndjson so that I can isolate the columns I want to filter for my analysis.

Thanks,
Hrishikesh

Answer (score -1):

`pandas.json_normalize` can help here. With pandas you can flatten json having multiple nested levels. Check out the following link on how to use the method:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html